# GSAP scroll animation in responsive layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, gsap

I'm making an animation for a computer image with GSAP

[When it works, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE6H2.gif)

But once I change the width of the window, everything in the layout is totally responsive but the animation.

[This is when it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOQTD.gif)

Below is a simple example
     https://codepen.io/littlecodingloser/pen/bGopwBv

How to make the animation responsive?

12/8 update

I add some method into start and end properties, and the problem is solved!

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Changed the post! Anything I can improve with it?

Comment: That edit didn't address the issue that I brought up - the lack of a minimal demo. Use something like CodePen to recreate the issue and strip out everything unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Codepen added! Hope that can help.

Comment: That demo does not recreate the issue. Please modify it to recreate the issue.

Comment: Doesn't it? Adjust the window into 450 pixels wide and you'll see that the animation stuck.

Comment: There is no animation. There is no scrolling.

Comment: I've modified it. How about now?

Comment: I've solved the prob! Thanks for pointing out the flaw of my post.